# MySQL 8.0.12: LOAD DATA INFILE giving ERROR 1290 secure_file_priv

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load data in MySQL using the following command in Windows 10:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/OneDrive/Documents/A/code/samsql/customer.csv'
INTO TABLE customers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I got the error

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I opened the my.ini file in the folder "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"
And I changed the secure-file-priv to

```
secure-file-priv="D:/"
```

But still I got the same error. Then based on some of the other threads I tried

```
secure-file-priv=""
```

But still I get the same error.
When I do

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

It returns

```
sevure_file_priv NULL
```

But still the error 1290 is there, and I cannot load the data. How do I resolve this?

Comment: this is not a duplicate, all the solutions there are not working @Shadow

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. You must have made a mistake when you implemented the solutions suggested there.